# com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0 and AndroidX migration

Tags: android, gradle, wear-os, androidx

I am trying to migrate my project to AndroidX but running into issues that appear related to com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0.

This library isn't migrated to AndroidX and appears to be dependent on other support libraries, which result in Dex merging errors like:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:72)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/os/ResultReceiver$1;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
    ... 1 more
```

I've tried excluding the support libraries in depends on by using

```
implementation ('com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-compat'
    }
```

but that just results in another error indicating that it's missing a required class:

```
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class android.support.wearable.complications.ComplicationHelperActivity, unresolved supertypes: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
```

Note that my gradle properties file does include:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Is using AndroidX not possible with WearOS code today?

Comment: If you've enabled Jetifier, it should process that dependency just fine. Are you sure it is that library that is causing your error?

Comment: @ianhanniballake fairly positive. I see the dependencies on com.android.support:support-compat from that library when running gradle dependencies, and excluding support-compat does partially fix the issue (but causes the other one mentioned in the question). That said, is there a way to verify that the Jetifier is actually doing its thing? The setting is there in gradle.properties, but maybe it's getting ignored?

Comment: Jetifier works fine on that library (its sole purpose is to rewrite dependencies) - my own app uses it without issue. Can you include what other dependencies your app pulls in?

Comment: You are able to use AndroidX libraries with WearOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033372/migrate-to-androidx-for-wear-support-libraries-after-android-pie