# Migrate to AndroidX for Wear Support Libraries after Android Pie?

Tags: dependencies, android-support-library, wear-os, androidx, migrate

Starting in Fall of 2019 the Google Play Console requires your wearable application targets at least Android 9 (API level 28).

- August 1, 2019: Required for new apps
- November 1, 2019: Required for app updates

After changing my `build.gradle` to target `29` it gives me a warning recommending I use AndroidX libraries when targeting Android Q or newer.

What should I change the `com.android.support` dependencies to?

```
implementation 'com.android.support:wear:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to the following solved the issue for me.

```
implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0’
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0’
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0’ // if you are using Kotlin
```

Also, if you right click > Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX… Android Studio will take care of the necessary migrations for you.

Comment: Careful, your text has hidden characters, and when copy/pasting it says "String end expected", "Unexpected character: '\''"